# Variable Dictionary Contents

Tags: javascript, node.js, roku

I'm not sure if this is possible, or if I'm taking the wrong approach, I've tried searching, but I'm not sure about the terms.

I would like to pass a variable into the controller dict, so rather than using 'PLAY', in the lookup I could do something like controller('OPTION','PLAY')

```
var ip = '192.168.1.5'
var Keys = {
            HOME:          '/keypress/Home',
            REV:           '/keypress/Rev',
            FWD:           '/keypress/Fwd',
            PLAY:          '/keypress/Play',
            SELECT:        '/keypress/Select',
            LEFT:          '/keypress/Left',
            RIGHT:         '/keypress/Right',
            DOWN:          '/keypress/Down',
            UP:            '/keypress/Up',
            BACK:          '/keypress/Back',
            INSTANTREPLAY: '/keypress/InstantReplay',
            INFO:          '/keypress/Info',
            BACKSPACE:     '/keypress/Backspace',
            SEARCH:        '/keypress/Search',
            ENTER:         '/keypress/Enter',
            A:             '/keypress/Lit_a'
     }
```

from this:

```
var controller = {
                  PLAY:{
                        hostname: ip,
                        port: 8060,
                        path: Keys['PLAY'],
                        method: 'POST'
                        }
                  }
```

to this:

```
var controller = {
                  OPTION:{
                        hostname: ip,
                        port: 8060,
                        path: Keys[Key],
                        method: 'POST'
                        }
                  }
```

I'm trying to avoid the following

```
var controller = {
                  PLAY:{
                        hostname: ip,
                        port: 8060,
                        path: Keys['PLAY'],
                        method: 'POST'
                        }
                  FWD :{
                        hostname: ip,
                        port: 8060,
                        path: Keys['FWD'],
                        method: 'POST'
                        }
                  REV :{
                        hostname: ip,
                        port: 8060,
                        path: Keys['REV'],
                        method: 'POST'
                        }
                  ...

                  }
```

Comment: And what is your problem exactly?

Comment: I don't wish to write a dictionary look up for each key, I.E. controller would have all the keys (referred to by keys) and I would be duplicating Hostname, Port, Method for each one, (lots of extra code for something that may have a shorter version, I.E. easier to read too)

Comment: So make a method `getOption("PLAY")` and return the object with the newly inserted path.

Comment: good call (I kinda feel dumb for not going that approach), however is something like what I suggested possible in this language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were you thinking of something like this:

```
controller = {
       OPTION : function(key){
                    return {
                    hostname: ip,
                    port: 8060,
                    path: Keys[key],
                    method: 'POST'
                   } 
                   }
              }
```

then you could get it with controller.OPTION("PLAY"). It is essentially creating the getOption() method epascerallo suggested just coupled into the controller object.